# JMeter for functional testing

Tags: functional-programming, jmeter, automated-tests

Does anyone know where I can find any JMeter video tutorials for functional testing? I have been searching for videos to utilize JMeter for functional testing and cant seem to find any.

Answer (score 1):

[Functional Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing) is a very broad term which covers lots of subtypes i.e.

- Unit Testing
- Smoke testing / Sanity testing
- Integration Testing (Top Down,Bottom up Testing)
- Interface & Usability Testing
- System Testing
- Regression Testing
- Pre User Acceptance Testing(Alpha & Beta)
- User Acceptance Testing
- White Box & Black Box Testing
- Globalization & Localization Testing

So it depends on what type sub-type of functional testing you need to implement.

If you're just going to use JMeter with limited number of threads, just look for any tutorial videos and ignore bits about virtual users and ramp-up and pay more attention to [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)

The best JMeter videos I can think of are listed under [The Ultimate JMeter Resource List](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ultimate-jmeter-resource-list) article

Comment: Can JMeter really be used for Functional Testing?